# ios swift - How do I keep a video playing while navigating the app

Tags: ios

Trying not to break the rules of stackExchange here. I want to play a video in a separate view, and be able to navigate around the app without having the video pause or stop.

I am using the youtube-ios-helper framework. I can control playback, and check state, and it pauses whenever I change views. This is a basic TabView App. One tabview is the player view, and there are 2 other tabviews that the user can interact with. The user must be able to navigate away from the video player view, and still hear the video being played (i.e. music video).

I am not set on a tabView, just want to be able to go back and forth between the music video and the other views in the app.

I am a novice developer trying to learn the ins and outs of the ios world. Please don't flame me.

Specific question: What is a good view type or design to use for my needs above? Ideally I would like to have the player view running in memory, and be able to place it anywhere within the app, at any time, while having the video playing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose to go with your current design. In this case, your app will be like this:

1) TabViewController controls VC A and VC B. in VC B, display Youtube Player. VC A is a flipviewcontroller, which control VC A1 and A2. A1 is where you search and display result. A2 is another Youtube player (Or A2 could also be VC B. You have a method to get a VC from TabViewController by its index). When tapping on Result in A1, A flip A1 and A2, so A2 will be display.

2) You can drop using TabViewController. You use only VC A - This is your initial viewcontroller. VC A is a flipviewcontroller, which control VC A1 and A2. A1 is where you search and display result. A2 contains a Youtube player. When tapping on Result in A1, A flip A1 and A2, so A2 will be display.

In both case A2 and B are retained by tabviewcontroller or flipviewcontroller, so it will not be release from memory.